# mockito NullInsteadOfMockException while stubbing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I want to mock a method call of a DAO class which use JDBC:

```
public class PointIssuanceLookupDao {
    public PointIssuanceLookupDao(@Qualifier("azureNamedParameterJdbcTemplate") NamedParameterJdbcTemplate azureNamedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
        this.azureNamedParameterJdbcTemplate = azureNamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    }
    ...

public CalcConstants retrieveCalcConstants (String productCode, String productSubCode){
    ....
    queryResultList = azureNamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(PRODUCT_RECON_DETAIL_SELECT, paramMap, queryValues);
    ....
```

This is my test case:

```
class PointIssuanceLookupDaoTest {

    @Mock
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

    private PointIssuanceLookupDao sut;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        sut = new PointIssuanceLookupDao(template);
    }

    @Test
    void retrieveCalcConstants() {
        SqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        List<Mapper> queryResultList = new ArrayList<>();

        doReturn(queryResultList).when(template).query(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(MapSqlParameterSource.class), ArgumentMatchers.<RowMapper<Mapper>>any());
        ...
```

I got error even when I stubbing the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate:

```
 PointIssuanceLookupDaoTest > retrieveCalcConstants() FAILED
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NullInsteadOfMockException: 
     Argument passed to when() is null!
     Example of correct stubbing:
         doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
     Also, if you use @Mock annotation don't miss openMocks()
         at com.abc.api.points.repository.dao.PointIssuanceLookupDaoTest.retrieveCalcConstants(PointIssuanceLookupDaoTest.java:49)
...
```

I called openMocks() in setUp(), why I still get this error?

Comment: Is `setUp` being run?

Comment: It was not run. What could be the reason that setUp was not run?

Comment: Which version of Junit are you using ?

Comment: @techie11 it's a moot point that won't correctly configure your mocks anyway.  But, since you asked, if the `@Before` method is not running, check that you're using the correct version of Junit.

Comment: I'm using Junit 5. I should use @BeforeEach

Comment: Yes, you need BeforeEach :) Using ExtendWith + InjectMocks, as suggested by @lane.maxwell, is a good idea, it would simplify your code.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell which version of JUnit you're using, but since you're using Spring, you don't have to manually set up these mocks.

If you're using JUnit5, just annotate your class with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, then just add `@InjectMocks` on the class under test.  You do not need to have a separate setup method.  If you're using JUnit4, use the `RunWith` annotation to setup the runner.  You should only be using openMocks if you're running with a different runner, like `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) // if Junit4
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) // if Junit5
class PointIssuanceLookupDaoTest {

  @Mock
  NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

  @InjectMocks
  private PointIssuanceLookupDao sut;
}
```

Comment: "but since you're using Spring, you don't have to manually set up these mocks." -> it has nothing to do with Spring. You can use the Runner or Extension + InjectMocks without Spring.

Comment: @SebPerp You're right; the runner has nothing to do with Spring.  That was intended to call out Spring's IoC capabilities, not the test runner.

Comment: oh ok I understand now what you meant.